# How to specify only methods for resource in array Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In web.php i have this Route::resources method

```php
Route::resources([
    'products' => App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::class,
    'categories' => App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController::class,
    'page-info' => App\Http\Controllers\PageInfoController::class,
]);
```

How can I specify only `index`,`edit` and `update` for 'page-info' route? and how to add name to each route?
I know that I can do it like this

```php
Route::resource('products', ProductsController::class);
Route::resource('page-info', PageInfoController::class)->only([
    'index', 'edit', 'update'
]);
//itd...
```

but I like the array one `resources` and thought it is possible too

Comment: I wonder if you could use an associative array, like `Route::resources(['products' => ['uses' => App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'only' => ['index', 'edit', 'update']], 'categories' => App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController::class, 'page-info' => App\Http\Controllers\PageInfoController::class])`. (Guessing at keys from older conventions)

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it fails.
I used your code and the error is: Array to string conversion
At: ResourceRegistrar.php:410
`protected function getResourceAction($resource, $controller, $method, $options)
{

        $name = $this->getResourceRouteName($resource, $method, $options);

        $action = ['as' => $name, 'uses' => $controller.'@'.$method]; // error here <--
        //rest of the function
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want, if the documentation does not explicitly say you can or not, you can always have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L305).

So, source code for Laravel 8.x has:

```php
/**
 * Register an array of resource controllers.
 *
 * @param  array  $resources
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return void
 */
public function resources(array $resources, array $options = [])
{
    foreach ($resources as $name => $controller) {
        $this->resource($name, $controller, $options);
    }
}
```

So, you can do

```php
Route::resources([
    'products' => App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::class,
    'categories' => App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController::class,
    'page-info' => App\Http\Controllers\PageInfoController::class,
], $options);
```

But the code shows that it will share the options for all the `resources` to be created, so the answer is a no, you can't (at least what I am looking at the source code).